# jQuery get keyup on current change on input and output live

Tags: php, jquery, html

I had attempted with the following code and a little stuck now but here is what I'm wanting to achieve:

1. enter value in input and update preview html below
2. once user is happy with preview output can click generate
3. once clicked generate it will actually write the preview HTML to a first_name-last_name.html file within that same folder and then redirect to the first_name-last_name.html file

jQuery / HTML form:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ambient Lounge - Create eSig</title>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro|Open+Sans+Condensed:300|Raleway' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!-- Include JS File Here -->
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <style type="text/css">
        @import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');

        body {
            font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }

        hr {
            margin-bottom: 1.5em;
        }

        .error_wrapper {
            color: #D8000C;
            background-color: #FFBABA;
            padding: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 1em;
        }

        .success_wrapper {
            color: #4F8A10;
            background-color: #DFF2BF;
            padding: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 1em;
        }

        #main {
            float: left;
            width: 20%;
        }

        #preview {
            float: left;
            width: 80%;
        }

        form label {
            display: none;
        }

        form input {
            margin-bottom: 0.5em;
            padding: 5px;
            width: 80%;
        }

    </style>
    <!-- Include JS File Here -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $(".error_wrapper, .success_wrapper").hide();

        var v_first_name = $("#first_name").val();
        var v_last_name = $("#last_name").val();
        var v_title = $("#title").val();
        var v_address = $("#address").val();
        var v_phone = $("#phone").val();
        var v_mobile = $("#mobile").val();
        var v_email = $("#email").val();
        var v_web = $("#web").val();

        $(".input_change").keyup(function(){
            $("#btn").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            var current_input = $(this).attr("id");
            console.log(current_input);
            $("#p_" + current_input).html($("#" + current_input).val());
        });

        $("#verify").click(function() {

            var has_error = false;

            $('#first_name, #last_name, #title, #address, #email, #web').each(function() {

                $(this).attr('style', 'border: 0;');

                if ($(this).val() == '') {
                    $(".error_msg").html("<strong>Error(s):</strong> You are missing some enteries, please check and try again.");
                    $(".error_wrapper").show();

                    $(this).attr('style', 'border: 1px solid red;');
                    has_error = true;
                }
            });

            if (has_error != true) {
                $(".error_wrapper").hide();
                alert("You have verified changes, please double check and if happy click create otherwise change values and verify again.");
                $("#btn").removeAttr('disabled');
            }

        });

        $("#btn").click(function() {
            $.post("create_post.php", { // Data Sending With Request To Server

                first_name:v_first_name,
                last_name:v_last_name,
                title:v_title,
                address:v_address,
                phone:v_phone,
                mobile:v_mobile,
                email:v_email,
                web:v_web

            }, function(response,status) { // Required Callback Function
                alert("*----Received Data----*\n\nStatus : " + status);//"response" receives - whatever written in echo of above PHP script.
                alert(response);
                if(status == "success") {
                    $("#form")[0].reset();
                } else {

                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Create e-mail signature</h2>
    <hr>
    <div class="error_wrapper">
        <div class="error_msg"></div>
        <ul></ul>
    </div>
    <div class="success_wrapper">
        <div class="success_msg"><strong>Congraulations!</strong> You have successfully create your e-mail signature. You can view your e-mail signature by clicking <a href="http://www.ambientlounge.com/emails/">here</a>.</div>
    </div>

    <div id="main">
        <form id="form" method="post">
            <label>First Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" class="input_change" placeholder="First name"/><br>
            <label>Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" class="input_change" placeholder="Last name"/><br>
            <label>Title</label>
            <input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="input_change" placeholder="Job title"/><br>
            <label>Address</label>
            <input type="text" name="address" id="address" class="input_change" placeholder="Business Address"/><br>
            <label>Phone</label>
            <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" class="input_change" placeholder="Phone number"/><br>
            <label>Mobile</label>
            <input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile" class="input_change" placeholder="Mobile number"/><br>
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="input_change" placeholder="Email address"/><br>
            <label>Web</label>
            <input type="text" name="web" id="web" class="input_change" placeholder="Web address"/>
        </form>
        <button id="verify">Verify</button> <button id="btn" disabled>Create</button>
    </div>

    <div id="preview">

        <!-- PREVIEW OF HTML EMAIL -->

        <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

        <style type="text/css">
            @import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');

            .clear {
                clear: both;
            }

            b {
                font-weight: normal;
            }

            b.bold {
                font-weight: bold;
            }

            .emailContent {
                font-family:'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
                width: 480px;
                color: #767676;
            }

            .emailContent a {
                color: #2A96B4;
                text-decoration: none;
            }

                .emailName {
                    height: 62px;
                }

                .emailName img {
                    float: right;
                    margin-top: 1.2em;
                    margin-right: 0.8em;
                }

                .emailName p {
                    color: #767676;
                    font-size: 0.8em;
                    float: left;
                }

                .emailName p span {
                    color: #2A96B4;
                    font-weight: bold;
                    font-size: 1.2em;
                }

                .emailLogo {
                    height: 46px;
                    clear: both;
                }

                .emailLogo img {
                    float: left;
                    margin-top: 0.3em;
                }

                .emailLogo ul.socialList {
                    list-style: none;
                    border-left: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
                    padding-left: 1.5em;
                    margin: 0 0 0 1.5em;
                    float: left;
                }

                .emailLogo ul.socialList li {
                    display: inline-block;
                }

                .emailLogo ul.socialList li img {
                    margin: 0;
                }

                .emailDetails {
                    clear: both;
                    border-top: 5px solid #2A96B4;
                    margin-top: 1em;
                }

                .emailDetails p {
                    font-size: 12px;
                    margin: 0.3em 0;
                }

                .emailDetails p.larger {
                    font-size: 14px;
                }

                .emailDetails p span { 
                    color: #2A96B4;
                }

            .emailNotice {
                border-top: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
                font-size: 0.6em;
                padding-top: 0.8em;
                margin-top: 2.5em;
            }

        </style>

        <div class="emailContent">
            <div class="emailName">
                <p><span><b id="p_first_name" class="bold">James</b> <b id="p_last_name" class="bold">Brandon</b></span><br><b id="p_title">Global Technical Lead</b></p>
                <img src="http://www.ambientlounge.com/emails/like-us-on-facebook.png" alt="Like us on Facebook" />
            </div>

            <div class="clear"></div>

            <div class="emailLogo">
                <img src="http://www.ambientlounge.com/emails/ambient-logo-email.png" alt="Ambient Lounge" />
                <ul class="socialList">
                    <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/ambientlounge" title="Ambient Lounge: Facebook"><img src="http://www.ambientlounge.com/emails/icon-facebook.png" alt="Facebook" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.twitter.com/ambientlounge" title="Ambient Lounge: Twitter"><img src="http://www.ambientlounge.com/emails/icon-twitter.png" alt="Twitter" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.instagram.com/ambientlounge" title="Ambient Lounge: Instagram"><img src="http://www.ambientlounge.com/emails/icon-instagram.png" alt="Instagram" /></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="clear"></div>

            <div class="emailDetails">
                <p><span>a:</span> <b id="p_address">Old knows Factory, Unit 5C, Office 14, St Anns Hill Road, Nottingham, NG3 4GN</b></p>
                <p><span>p:</span> <b id="p_phone">+44(0) 844 579 1112</b> | <span>m:</span> <b id="p_mobile">+44(0) 771 809 0 809</b></p>
                <p class="larger"><a href="mailto:sarah@ambientlounge.co.uk"><span id="p_email">james@ambientlounge.com</b></a> | <a href="http://www.ambientlounge.co.uk/"><b id="p_web">www.ambientlounge.co.uk</b></a></p>
            </div>

            <p class="emailNotice">This email and any files transmitted with it are confidential and intended solely for the use of the individual or entity to whom they are addressed. If you have received this email in error please notify the system manager. This message contains confidential information and is intended only for the individual named. If you are not the named addressee you should not disseminate, distribute or copy this e-mail. Please notify the sender immediately by e-mail if you have received this e-mail by mistake and delete this e-mail from your system. If you are not the intended recipient you are notified that disclosing, copying, distributing or taking any action in reliance on the contents of this information is strictly prohibited.</p>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Current PHP Post file:

```
<?php
    if($_POST["first_name"]) {
        $first_name = $_POST["first_name"];
        $last_name = $_POST["last_name"];
        $title = $_POST["title"];
        $address = $_POST["address"];
        $phone = $_POST["phone"];
        $mobile = $_POST["mobile"];
        $email = $_POST["email"];
        $web = $_POST["web"];

        $filePath == $first_name + "-" + $last_name + ".html";

        if(file_exists($filePath)){
            echo "Already exisits";
        } else {
            touch( $filePath ); //create file if it does not exist

            fwrite( $file, '
            <html>
                <head>
                    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
                    <title>Ambient Lounge - e-Mail Signature (James Brandon)</title>
                    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
                    <style type="text/css">
                        @import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans");

                        .clear {
                            clear: both;
                        }

                        .emailContent {
                            font-family:"Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
                            width: 480px;
                            color: #767676;
                        }

                        .emailContent a {
                            color: #2A96B4;
                            text-decoration: none;
                        }

                            .emailName {
                                height: 62px;
                            }

                            .emailName img {
                                float: right;
                                margin-top: 1.2em;
                                margin-right: 0.8em;
                            }

                            .emailName p {
                                color: #767676;
                                font-size: 0.8em;
                                float: left;
                            }

                            .emailName p span {
                                color: #2A96B4;
                                font-weight: bold;
                                font-size: 1.2em;
                            }

                            .emailLogo {
                                height: 46px;
                                clear: both;
                            }

                            .emailLogo img {
                                float: left;
                                margin-top: 0.3em;
                            }

                            .emailLogo ul.socialList {
                                list-style: none;
                                border-left: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
                                padding-left: 1.5em;
                                margin: 0 0 0 1.5em;
                                float: left;
                            }

                            .emailLogo ul.socialList li {
                                display: inline-block;
                            }

                            .emailLogo ul.socialList li img {
                                margin: 0;
                            }

                            .emailDetails {
                                clear: both;
                                border-top: 5px solid #2A96B4;
                                margin-top: 1em;
                            }

                            .emailDetails p {
                                font-size: 12px;
                                margin: 0.3em 0;
                            }

                            .emailDetails p.larger {
                                font-size: 14px;
                            }

                            .emailDetails p span { 
                                color: #2A96B4;
                            }

                        .emailNotice {
                            border-top: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
                            font-size: 0.6em;
                            padding-top: 0.8em;
                            margin-top: 2.5em;
                        }

                    </style>

                <div class="emailContent">
            ');
            fwrite( $file, '
                <div class="emailName">
                    <p><span>'.$first_name.' '.$last_name.'</span><br>'.$title.'</p>
                    <img src="http://www.ambientlounge.com/emails/like-us-on-facebook.png" alt="Like us on Facebook" />
                </div>

                <div class="clear"></div>

                <div class="emailLogo">
                    <img src="http://www.ambientlounge.com/emails/ambient-logo-email.png" alt="Ambient Lounge" />
                    <ul class="socialList">
                        <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/ambientlounge" title="Ambient Lounge: Facebook"><img src="http://www.ambientlounge.com/emails/icon-facebook.png" alt="Facebook" /></a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://www.twitter.com/ambientlounge" title="Ambient Lounge: Twitter"><img src="http://www.ambientlounge.com/emails/icon-twitter.png" alt="Twitter" /></a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://www.instagram.com/ambientlounge" title="Ambient Lounge: Instagram"><img src="http://www.ambientlounge.com/emails/icon-instagram.png" alt="Instagram" /></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="clear"></div>

                <div class="emailDetails">
                    <p><span>a:</span> '.$address.'</p>
                    <p><span>p:</span> '.$phone.' | <span>m:</span> '.$mobile.'</p>
                    <p class="larger"><a href="mailto:'.$email.'">'.$email.'</a> | <a href="http://'.$web.'/">'.$web.'</a></p>
                </div>
            ');
            fwrite( $file, '
                        <p class="emailNotice">This email and any files transmitted with it are confidential and intended solely for the use of the individual or entity to whom they are addressed. If you have received this email in error please notify the system manager. This message contains confidential information and is intended only for the individual named. If you are not the named addressee you should not disseminate, distribute or copy this e-mail. Please notify the sender immediately by e-mail if you have received this e-mail by mistake and delete this e-mail from your system. If you are not the intended recipient you are notified that disclosing, copying, distributing or taking any action in reliance on the contents of this information is strictly prohibited.</p>
                    </div>

                </body>
            </html>
            ');

            $file = fopen( $filePath, "w" );
            fwrite( $file, $data );
            fclose( $file );

            $data = file_get_contents( $filePath ); //do this after closing your writing
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Where are you stuck? One issue, you don't have a `$_POST["name"]` so your PHP will never fire.

Comment: Im just at the point getting values from inputs when changing values and writting to preview html... i only added a couple of divs with ids to rewrite the html

Comment: So just sorted the change of input value and updating HTML preview, just would need some help when passing to write to a new html file now and done :)

Comment: Is it a requirement that you actually create a preview file?  Otherwise, you could create a php endpoint that takes the inputs, validates, and generates the html to be returned, which could be displayed in an iframe or a modal of some sort.

Comment: So ive updated the code, when you enter value in input will update the preview HTML, once the submit button is hit what i need it to do is take that preview HTML "or the new values" pass to the PHP Post template and replace the values and write to a new html file on the server.

Comment: Change $firstnamevaraible to $first_name and $lastnamevariable to $last_name and so on and so forth and your on the right track.  Or at least 'a' right track, :)

Comment: This looks like it has a helpful answer, so could you add an [mcve] to help the question stay open? What specific help did you need at the time? Presently it says "I am stuck with this code, please help me", and I wonder if that is not very useful for future readers. (Aside, if you are not aware, we try to maintain old questions here, even if they are no longer useful to the original poster).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write to a file with:

```
touch( $filePath ); //create file if it does not exist
$file = fopen( $filePath, "w" );
fwrite( $file, $data );
fclose( $file );
```

This will replace the entire file contents with what you fwrite().
You can check if a file already exists with

```
file_exists( $filePath );
```

You can define your custom file path in a manner like

```
$filePath = "whatever directory you want it to go to/". $firstnamevariable ."-". $lastnamevariable .".html";
```

You can keep a running $data variable that you write to the file at the end by appending to, like how $filePath above is appending.  Or you can simply write to the file multiple time.

```
fwrite( $file, "<html><head></head><body>" );
fwrite( $file, "<div>First Name: ". $firstnamevaraible ."</div>" );
fwrite( $file, "<div>Last Name: ". $lastnamevariable ."</div>" );
fwrite( $file, "</body></html>" );
```

Once you've created your file, if you want to return the entire contents to the user you can do

```
$data = file_get_contents( $filePath ); //do this after closing your writing
```

Then you can echo $data to the user or if you want, just echo that function without the need for a variable.

Comment: In the PHP post file, how would i set data for the tpl? like $data = ""; and place everything within side that varible?

Comment: As a simple method, you could instantiate data to be $data = "";  then as you generate the page, just append to it with $data .= "whatever_html_data_you_want_to_create";

Comment: ok i think i can crack writting the data to the file, how can i set the custom file name? as i want to use first_name-last_name.html - also what condition would i add if that file already exists? like if first-last.html exist show error, else write or even better if it does exist show another button to verify overwrite? that literally would be last hurdle and im done lol

Comment: i have made some changes, and update question can you check? post file anyway am i doing the right thing? also is it exists would like to confirm overwrite if possible but if a pain dont worry.

Comment: Added the function to read the file at the end so you can return the data to the requestor.

Comment: Thanks mate, think im almost there but still a little lost on something. ive update question again qith latest can you check for me? ive also added success msg and condition (not complete) but would like to get file url back to success msg and also its not creating file etc....

Comment: You got $filePath == "string".  That's a boolean comparison.  You want a single equals for assignment.  Also you have some fwrite() before your fopen().  You have to open the file before you can write to it.  Touch, open to write, write (*n) times, close, read contents, return contents

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76399/discussion-between-james-and-taplar).